# {}.hasOwnProperty('id'); returns syntax error in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I played around in the Chrome console and wondered why this statement throws a syntax error:

```
{}.hasOwnProperty('id');
```

My expectation was the return value `false`.
A syntax error also occurs in Firefox and IE .
The same works if I use an empty array instead of an empty object.
The same also works if I put braces around:

```
({}.hasOwnProperty('id'));
```

Comment: FYI: `({}).hasOwnProperty('id');` works, too.

Comment: `{}` without surrounding parentheses (or an operator applied) is parsed as a statement block, not an object literal.

Comment: In this case, `{}` will be interpreted as a block statement rather than an object literal.

Comment: Object.hasOwnProperty('id'); return false. I think something about naming convention could explain that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's syntax ambiguity in snippet in question. Curly braces in JavaScript have two meanings: they are used to delimit code blocks, for example:

```
if (x) {
    ...
}
```

and they are used to declare object literals:

```
var obj = {
    prop: "value"
}
```

Constext is used to differentiate between the two interpretations, and in case of:

```
{}.hasOwnProperty('id');
```

braces are resolved to block declaration, so this yields syntax error. On the other hand:

```
({}.hasOwnProperty('id'));
```

One cannot declare block inside parentheses, so `{}` is recognized as object literal in this context.

Comment: This is a complete answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

*{}* is treated as a statement block *rather than an object*, as you are expecting. Hence the error.

**EDIT**: As @Cerbrus mentioned in the comments, *({}).hasOwnProperty('id');* would return false and not an error. This is because when surrounding {} with parenthesis, it is interpreted as an Object.